# Module csv has no attribute excel

Tags: python, tensorflow

When I import TensorFlow GPU then I get the following error, please help

```py
import tensorflow as tf
```

> Attribute Error: module csv has no attribute excel

Comment: You just have a single line of code, just import `tensorflow as tf`? Nothing else?

Comment: Good comment by Mrinal Roy, put yourself in the shoes of people wanting to answer the question and give as much information as possible to lead to a quick answer.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you have a file called `csv.py` in your parent folder where you're running the Python script above. To get rid of this error, you should rename your `csv.py` file to something else. It conflicts with Python's [CSV module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html).

TensorFlow uses the CSV module for [data reading and preparation](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/search?q=%22import+csv%22&unscoped_q=%22import+csv%22) and specifically calls `csv.excel` in its Keras callback [implementation](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/keras/callbacks.py#L2516).